# How do I show that $ \sin x, \cos x$ really are in $ [-1,1]$ using series notion?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, proof-verification, research

I'm sorry to ask this question , but should ask it may help me to know more

about series theory , It is well known that  $\cos x $ and $\sin x$  are

represented  by alternative series  which hard for me to show wether sinx and

cosx are in this range $[-1,1]$ .

**My question here** :Is there analytical proof show that $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ both are really in $[-1,1]$ using series theory if it is possible

**Note**: I do not want to use geometric interpretation because it is standard at all

Thank you for any help

Comment: Quick note, you mean range not domain.

Comment: yes , i meant range

Comment: You can prove that $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ just from the series — multiply the sine and cosine series by themselves and add. This implies that $-1\le\sin x\le 1$ (why?).

Comment: I've not scrolled down but immediately I'd look at calculus. Finding a minimum and maximum will work.

Comment: it is showed in the answer of themaker, f(0)=1 ?,?,,,,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the series is easy to prove that (using the fact that power series can be differentiated term by term inside the disk of convergence)
$$\frac{d}{dx} \cos(x) = -\sin(x)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx} \sin(x) = \cos(x)$$
If we define
$$F(x) := \cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x)$$
then
$F(0) = 1$ and
$$\frac{d}{dx}F(x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x) - 2\cos(x)\sin(x)= 0\ \ \forall x\in \mathbb R$$
hence $F$ is constant
$$F(x) = \cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1 \ \ \forall x\in \mathbb R$$
From this is clear that
$$|\cos(x)|\leq 1 \ \ \forall x\in \mathbb R$$
$$|\sin(x)|\leq 1 \ \ \forall x\in \mathbb R$$

Comment: I love this answer. somehow never realized the derivative of sin^2+cos^2 is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Using series, you can prove (by defining $\exp$, $\sin$ and $\cos$ as series) that

$$\forall x\in\Bbb C,e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$$

$$\forall x \in \Bbb R, |e^{ix}|=1$$

And from there, it's easy to see that

$$|\sin x|\le |e^{ix}|=1$$

$$|\cos x|\le |e^{ix}|=1$$

Comment: I think sinx and cosx are both represented by alternative series and only you are used Euler formula .

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Euler's formula is PROVEN using series.

Comment: Given that Euler's formula is proven by series, it's not immediately clear why $|e^{ix}|=1$, as this fact requires $\cos(x)^2+\sin(x)^2=1$ as in themaker's answer. It's not hard to show this with some more work but, without it this does feel like cheating.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik this proof is not all that different than themaker's-themaker's proof uses the Euclidean plane, and xaviermo2 uses the Argand plane. In fact, it is sometimes more efficient to start with the complex definition and "restrict" it to the real line.

Comment: How did you conclude that $|e^{ix}|=1$? That's trivial if you know _already_ that $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ are real and $(\cos x)^2+(\sin x)^2=1$, but how would you know that if you just start with the two series? Whatever your answer to that question, it should be explained above. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy : If $x$ is real, then $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are infinite sums of real numbers so they can only converge to a real number. And $(\cos x)^2+(\sin x)^2=1$ can either be derived as in the other answer by differentiation, or you can just compute the series as Cauchy products (which is basically brute force and I thought would be obvious to anyone familiar with series).

Comment: @xavierm02 : I think you should say explicitly in your answer you you conclude that.  What happens when you take Cauchy products doesn't seem self-evident. ${}\qquad{}$